# Динамическое изменение списка второго спиннера при выборе элемента первого

Tags: android, kotlin

имеются переменные которые берут данные из позиции спинера и текста в эдитвиве. как намекнуть в коде что иногда (при изменение значения) нужно снова считать данные в переменных и вывести их на экран.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var data = arrayOf("one", "two", "three")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var tetOne = myProviders(name = "one", rank = 0, product = "trees")
        var tetTwo = myProviders(name = "two", rank = 1, product = "ygol")
        var tetThree = myProviders(name = "three", rank = 2, product = "silitra")

        var Pro = arrayOf(tetOne, tetTwo, tetThree)

        var tetProdOne = Production(name = "Ygol1", rankPost = 0, price = 100)
        var tetProdTwo = Production(name = "Tgol2", rankPost = 0, price = 102)
        var tetProdThree = Production(name = "Ygol3", rankPost = 0, price = 103)
        var tetProdFour = Production(name = "Ygol4", rankPost = 1, price = 104)
        var tetProdFive = Production(name = "Ygol5", rankPost = 1, price = 105)
        var tetProdSix = Production(name = "Ygol6", rankPost = 1, price = 106)
        var tetProdSeven = Production(name = "Ygol7", rankPost = 2, price = 107)
        var tetProdEith = Production(name = "Ygol8", rankPost = 2, price = 108)
        var tetProdNine = Production(name = "Ygol9", rankPost = 2, price = 109)

        var Tov = arrayOf(tetProdOne, tetProdTwo, tetProdThree, tetProdFour, tetProdFive, tetProdSix, tetProdSeven, tetProdEith, tetProdNine)

        /* var qro: ArrayAdapter<myProviders> = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Pro)
         qro.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
         spOne.adapter=qro*/
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        val spinner = findViewById(R.id.spPost) as Spinner
        val priceMass = findViewById(R.id.priceMass) as TextView
        val reqMass = findViewById(R.id.reqMass) as TextView
        val shippingCost = findViewById(R.id.shippingCost) as TextView
        val allPrice = findViewById(R.id.allPrice) as TextView
        spinner.adapter = adapter
        spinner.prompt = "Title"
        spinner.setSelection(2)
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View,
                                        position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // viwOne.setText(Pro[position].name)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
        var spinpos: Int
        var price: Int = 0
        var totalPrice: Int = 0
        var req: Int = 0
        spinpos = spinner.selectedItemPosition
        val pr = arrayListOf<String>()
        var inde: Int = 0
        for (i in Tov) {
            if (Pro[spinpos].rank == Tov[inde].rankPost) {
                pr.add(Tov[inde].name)
            }
            inde++
        }
        val arc = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pr)
        arc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        val spinnerTwo = findViewById(R.id.spProd) as Spinner
        spinnerTwo.adapter = arc
        spinnerTwo.prompt = "Title"
        spinnerTwo.setSelection(2)
        spinnerTwo.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View,
                                        position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "NeTaPosition = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // viwOne.text = spinpos.toString()
                inde = 0
                for (i in Tov) {
                    if (pr[position] == Tov[inde].name) {
                        price = Tov[inde].price
                    }
                    inde++
                }
                priceMass.text = price.toString()
                reqMass.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
                    override fun onKey(v: View, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
                        if (event.getAction() === KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                            val strCatName = reqMass.text.toString()
                            totalPrice = price.toInt() * strCatName.toInt()
                            allPrice.text = totalPrice.toString()
                            return true
                        }
                        return false
                    }
                }
                                        )
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
    }
}

class Production(val name: String = "", val rankPost: Int = 0, val price: Int = 0) {}
class myProviders(val name: String = "", val rank: Int = 0, val product: String = "") {}
```

Comment: spinpos=spinner.selectedItemPosition  собственно и нужно позванивать

Comment: не получается сделать вычисление в полях в зависимости от выбора name = "one",name = "two" name = "three". в идеале когда я выдергиваю позицию из первого Spenner'a во втором должны обновятся поля на основе позиции. Но так как в spinpos записывается самое первое значение при старте приложения то нечего не происходить (значения не меняются)

Comment: priceMass выводится в поле значение в зависимости от выбранного Tov[].name выбранного в Spinner'е. а вот содержимое самого Spinner'а не меняется в зависимости от выбора  Pro[].name в первом Spinner'е

Comment: Чувствую себя фашистом, пытающим пленного партизана "Сколько у вас танков!?" :) Т.е. вопрос такой "Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе значения в одном спиннере менялся список элементов во втором и для второго срабатывал его `onItemSelected`?"

Comment: В принципе да.это все что нужно.ну и еще(если можно )совет по изменению кода(если есть что то особенно странное)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корень всех бед в пренебреджении лучшими практиками написания кода. Рекомендую к прочтению книгу Роберта Мартина "Чистый код". То, что у вас - называется спагетти-код и это крайне негативно сказывается на понимании того, как он работает.

Для начала давайте оставим в `onCreate` самый высокий уровень абстракции. Так мы начнем хоть немного ориентироваться в происходящем. (Раскидаем лопатой, без изысков. Переменные в свойства класса, логику в методы)

Дисклаймер: делал в блокноте, так что скорее всего код ниже содержит ошибки. Однако основной идеей является показать направление движения.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var data = arrayOf("one", "two", "three")

    lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter
    lateinit var arc: ArrayAdapter
    lateinit var spinner: Spinner
    lateinit var spinnerTwo: Spinner
    lateinit var priceMass: TextView
    lateinit var reqMass: TextView
    lateinit var shippingCost: TextView
    lateinit var allPrice: TextView

    var inde: Int = 0
    var price: Int = 0
    var totalPrice: Int = 0
    var req: Int = 0
    val pr = ArrayList<String>()

    var Pro = arrayOfMyProviderss()
    var Tov = arrayOfProductions()

    val spinnerInitialPosition = 2

    var spinpos: Int = spinnerInitialPosition

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        bindView()

        makeSpinnerTwoContent()

        spinner = makeSpinner(R.id.spPost, adapter, "Title", spinnerInitialPosition, spinnerListener())
        spinnerTwo = makeSpinner(R.id.spProd, arc, "Title", 2, spinnerTwoListener())
    }

    private fun spinnerListener(): OnItemSelectedListener {
        return object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                spinpos = position
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
    }

    private fun makeSpinnerTwoContent() {
        for (i in Tov) {
            if (Pro[spinpos].rank == Tov[inde].rankPost) {
                pr.add(Tov[inde].name)
            }
            inde++
        }
    }

    private fun spinnerTwoListener(): OnItemSelectedListener {
        return object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "NeTaPosition = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                makeSpinnerTwoContent()
                priceMass.text = price.toString()
                reqMass.setOnKeyListener(reqMassListener())
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
    }

    private fun reqMassListener(): View.OnKeyListener =
            object : View.OnKeyListener {
                override fun onKey(v: View, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
                    if (event.getAction() === KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        val strCatName = reqMass.text.toString()
                        totalPrice = price * strCatName.toInt()
                        allPrice.text = totalPrice.toString()
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                }
            }


    private fun makeSpinner(resource: Int, adapter: ArrayAdapter, title: String, selection: Int, listener: OnItemSelectedListener): Spinner {
        val spinner = findViewById(resource) as Spinner
        spinner.adapter = adapter
        spinner.prompt = title
        spinner.setSelection(selection)
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = listener
        return spinner
    }

    private fun bindView() {
        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data)
        arc = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pr)
        priceMass = findViewById(R.id.priceMass) as TextView
        reqMass = findViewById(R.id.reqMass) as TextView
        shippingCost = findViewById(R.id.shippingCost) as TextView
        allPrice = findViewById(R.id.allPrice) as TextView
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        arc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    }

    private fun arrayOfMyProviderss(): Array<myProviders> {
        val tetOne = myProviders(name = "one", rank = 0, product = "trees")
        val tetTwo = myProviders(name = "two", rank = 1, product = "ygol")
        val tetThree = myProviders(name = "three", rank = 2, product = "silitra")

        return arrayOf(tetOne, tetTwo, tetThree)
    }

    private fun arrayOfProductions(): Array<Production> {
        val tetProdOne = Production(name = "Ygol1", rankPost = 0, price = 100)
        val tetProdTwo = Production(name = "Tgol2", rankPost = 0, price = 102)
        val tetProdThree = Production(name = "Ygol3", rankPost = 0, price = 103)
        val tetProdFour = Production(name = "Ygol4", rankPost = 1, price = 104)
        val tetProdFive = Production(name = "Ygol5", rankPost = 1, price = 105)
        val tetProdSix = Production(name = "Ygol6", rankPost = 1, price = 106)
        val tetProdSeven = Production(name = "Ygol7", rankPost = 2, price = 107)
        val tetProdEith = Production(name = "Ygol8", rankPost = 2, price = 108)
        val tetProdNine = Production(name = "Ygol9", rankPost = 2, price = 109)

        return arrayOf(tetProdOne, tetProdTwo, tetProdThree, tetProdFour, tetProdFive, tetProdSix, tetProdSeven, tetProdEith, tetProdNine)
    }
}

class Production(val name: String = "", val rankPost: Int = 0, val price: Int = 0) {}
class myProviders(val name: String = "", val rank: Int = 0, val product: String = "") {}
```

Теперь смотрим задачу.

Вам надо менять состав второго спиннера в зависимости от выбора в первом. Для этого необходимо 1) очистить `pr` 2) Залить его новыми значениями 3) сказать второму спиннеру(адаптеру), что данные поменялись. И все это в `onItemSelected` первого спиннера.

```
private fun spinnerListener(): OnItemSelectedListener {
    return object : OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            spinpos = position
            makeSpinnerTwoContent()   //пересоздаем список
            arc.notifyDataSetChanged()   //сообщаем адаптеру
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {}
    }
}

private fun makeSpinnerTwoContent() {
    pr.clear()  //очищаем список
    for (i in Tov) {
        if (Pro[spinpos].rank == Tov[inde].rankPost) {
            pr.add(Tov[inde].name)
        }
        inde++
    }
}
```